# React Redux - Unable to resolve "./components/Provider" from "node_modules\react-redux\lib\index.js"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

The development server returned response error code: 500 \n\n
Unable to resolve "./components/Provider" from "node_modules\react-redux\lib\index.js"

```
BodyX:
{"originModulePath":"C:\\Users\\MY PC\\Documents\\Projects\\snapfood-customer\\node_modules\\react-redux\\lib\\index.js","targetModuleName":"./components/Provider","message":"Unable to resolve module `./components/Provider` from `C:\\Users\\MY PC\\Documents\\Projects\\snapfood-customer\\node_modules\\react-redux\\lib\\index.js`: The module `./components/Provider` could not be found from `C:\\Users\\MY PC\\Documents\\Projects\\snapfood-customer\\node_modules\\react-redux\\lib\\index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:\n\n
```

my code is as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import store from './app/index';
import WelcomeScreen from './app/WelcomeScreen';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <WelcomeScreen/>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Check you have installed the dependencies set in `package.json` after you check you have defined a `react-redux` dependency on it.

Comment: already done that

Comment: any other suggestion please?